# Arguments in C++ not received correctly from the Bash

Tags: c++, bash, arguments

A debug version of my C++ code starts with:

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
        for(int i=0;i<argc;++i)
        {
                cout<<"argv["<<i<<"]="<<argv[i]<<endl;
        }
}
```

When a customer starts this software from the Bash using the command:

```
../Merge-2021-11-22_0906_NOVEMBER_DEV9-Ubuntu20.04_x86_64/merge --autoXML merge_combine_command_small_testcase/input.xml -o autoxml -M "-F 0.3 -I -o mergeout"
```

it prints:

```
argv[0]=/mnt/raid/1_Merge_Kernel_testing/combined_command_testing/Merge-2021-11-22_0906_NOVEMBER_DEV9-Ubuntu20.04_x86_64/bin/merge
argv[1]=--autoXML
argv[2]=merge_combine_command_small_testcase/input.xml
argv[3]=-o
argv[4]=autoxml
argv[5]=-M
argv[6]=-F
argv[7]=0.3
argv[8]=-I
argv[9]=-o
argv[10]=mergeout
```

...which is not correct because due to the double quotes argv[6] should be:

```
argv[6]=-F 0.3 -I -o mergeout
```

This is strange because it happens only on the customer's system while the Bash on my computer does it correctly. Initially I thought the problem is that his shell does not interpret the double quotes. But I wrote this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo param0: ${0}
echo param1: ${1}
echo param2: ${2}
echo param3: ${3}
echo param4: ${4}
echo param5: ${5}
echo param6: ${6}
echo param7: ${7}
echo param8: ${8}
echo param9: ${9}
echo param10: ${10}
echo param11: ${11}
echo param12: ${12}
```

and it prints the parameters correctly on his and on my system. Now I don't know how to debug this further. Any ideas what can cause the different behavior?

Comment: Is your customer Windows-based, by any chance?

Comment: What shell does your customer have? This is 100% a shell problem and nothing you can fix in code. They might have to escape the quotes. Shell rules around quotes varies widely.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that your customer is using bash and not some other shell? (Ask for the output of `$SHELL`.) When they start it from "the Bash", is that manually entered in the terminal, or by executing a script?

Comment: @Geom : Your customer is most likely not running bash. Ask him to do a `echo $BASH_VERSION` right before invoking your program.

Comment: However, I am not aware of any other language which would exhibit the behaviour you are describing. Aside from the `echo` check I mentioned above, I would request a screen shot from the customer to exactly see what he is doing.

Comment: Assuming that only bash is involved, and not on a Windows system, then my **suspicion** is that there is a bash *script* involved somewhere, and in that bash script the parameters are **not** being properly expanded such that they are not later re-parsed into separate arguments.

Comment: May it be that the customer put ''(two single quotes) instead " (double quotes)?

Comment: @AskoldIlvento: Already checked. He has sent me the command in an ASCII file. It's an Ubuntu system

Comment: @Eljay: Good point. This might happen. I just asked the customer if he redirects the command using a script.

Comment: @Eljay: It's as you assumed. The customer used a script with the same name as the executable and he forwarded the parameters with $@ instead of "${@}". [x] solved, thank you very much!

Comment: Excellent!  Mystery solved.  (If Windows was involved, it could have been the same kind of problem, but using different shells, which makes the problem harder to sleuth and harder to resolve.)